# How to determine if a particular Chrome Browser Extension is installed, with no relationship to the Extension Provider

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How can I determine if a particular Chrome Browser Extension is installed, with no relationship to the Extension Provider?

It is a 'content script' (i.e. javascript running in the context of a web page) and so does not have access to chrome.i18n, chrome.extension, chrome.management objects.

The scenario is, a person has clicked on a link to an RSS feed.  But as at current Chrome does not  natively support the RSS/atom feed protocol, and presentation of RSS feeds in Google Chrome is best mediated by one or another of several available RSS Feed Reader Extensions.

We're recommending use of "RSS Subscription Extension (by Google)" and would like to offer the suggestion to the user that they install this Chrome Extension - download link and all - - **but of course, only in the case they haven't already installed it.**

How can I query the list of extensions installed into a running Chrome Browser?

Comment: I suspect that that information is deliberately kept private.

Comment: There is [chrome.management.get](http://developer.chrome.com/stable/extensions/management.html#method-get) method. If it's what you need, I can post the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try chrome.extension.getViews(object fetchProperties) which will return an array of the JavaScript 'window' objects for each of the pages running inside the current extension or chrome.management.getAll(function callback) which returns a list of information about installed extensions and apps.

Comment: The user explicitly said this wasn't possible because the code is running in userspace. Do you have any method of accessing this info that he missed?